# Proving set equality that involves set differences more than once

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have tried proving the following identity, but I am not sure how to proceed from this point forward.

That is what I am trying to prove: $A - (A-B) = A \cap B$

I tried introducing an $a$ that exists in the left hand side to show it also exists in the right hand side like so,

 Let $a \in A - (A-B)$
$\iff$ $a \in A $ and $a \notin (A-B)$
$\iff$ $a \in A $ and $a \notin A$ or $a \in B$

 Isn't this line is a contradiction since $a\in A$ and at the same time $a \notin A$?

I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong..

Comment: OR $a\in B$ and $a\in A$

Comment: So, can we just get rid of the fact $a \notin A$ since it's $\notin$?

Comment: Well it's not possible that $a\in A$ and $a\notin A$ so we can discard that possibility.

Comment: I see. So, then would it be fine to re-write it just as $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ since this can't be true?

Comment: You need to add parentheses you your words as in $a \in A$ and ( either $a \notin A$ or $a \in B$). This is the same as $a \in A$ and $a \in B$.

Comment: If you want to convince your teacher you know what you are doing, you might rewrite it first as $(a\in A \text{ and } a\notin A) \text{ or } (a\in A\text{ and } a\in B)$

Comment: The last line in your proof isn't contradictory, what's the issue is you didn't parenthesise. That is, the last line should be $a \in A$ and ($a \not\in A$ or $a \in B$). This is equivalent to "$a \in A$ and $a \in B$" (and thus $a \in A \cap B$), since, as you observed, the $a \not\in A$ part of the parenthesised expression would be contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prove it formally:

$A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$ and $A \setminus (A \cap B^c) = A \cap ( A \cap B^c)^c = A \cap (A^c \cup B)= A \cap B$.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't my proof be formal though since I'm just simplifying the expression?

Comment: Your proof is essentially the same thing just with elements.